# Editing hyperlink to remove file name from path

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to alter hyperlinks within an open Outlook email to remove the filename from the path. For example I want A:\test\folder1\file.txt to become A:\test\folder1

We use SharePoint Online to store files and often want to open the file location instead. Modifying the link makes this happen (we have SharePoint mapped as a network share).

This code alters the entire hyperlink. I assume I need to discard everything after the final backslash.

```vb
Sub HyperLinkChange()
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim tmpLink As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    If ActiveInspector.EditorType = olEditorWord Then
        ' use WordEditor Inspector
        Set objDoc = ActiveInspector.WordEditor
        For Each tmpLink In objDoc.Hyperlinks
            tmpLink.Address = "test123"
        Next tmpLink
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `InStrRev` to search for a backslash starting from the end, and `Left` function to truncate your string. For more detail, see the [InStrRev documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/instrrev-function) and [Left documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/left-function).

After adding an additional variable `Dim pos as Long`, find the position of the last backslash with `pos = InStrRev(tmpLink.Address, "\", , vbTextCompare)`. This is the postion starting from **beginning** of the address text, not the end. In your example address `A:\test\folder1\file.txt`, the position of the last backslash is 16.

Then `tmpLink.Address = Left(tmpLink.Address, pos - 1)` returns everything to the left of that backslash.

Comment: Thanks! This works great, really appreciate the help. The only issue I have now is that the macro only works if the active email reply is in a popped out window? If I just click reply and try to run it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, because you're using `ActiveInspector`... Can you be more clear, you do want to work with an **open**  email? What is not working when you click reply?

Comment: Hi, yes would like it to work with the current email being read. So if someone sends me an email to my Outlook with a link in it that i want to run this macro on and i click reply to make that email "active" and run the macro nothing happens. If I then just click the "pop out" to have the email display in its own window and run it again it works fine.

Comment: Or if its possible to make this work without having to click reply even better.

Comment: To work with the current email being read, Instead of `ActiveInspector`, you need to use `ActiveExplorer`, e.g. looking at `ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)`. With this approach, you'll have to modify the `Body` or `HTMLBody` of the `Item`, making sure it's a `MailItem` in the first place. Finding and modifying the hyperlinks is doable but almost an entirely different question/approach. Sadly no convenience of using the `WordEditor`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand the general principles of what you are saying. When I click reply its using the a live word editor and so completely different than when i'm just viewing highlighted mail via the preview pane. I have some books on the way so will post back if I make any headway.